# Manchester encoder/decoder

Tags: c++, optimization, beginner, array

I have written a [Manchester Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) encoder / decoder based on my misconception of how it works (*whoops*). My encoder accepts an array of ones and zeroes, and returns the 'manchester encoded' data (pretending there is a constant clock to overlay onto the data). I am reasonably new to C++, and would like to advance my knowledge and coding skill in it, hence why I coded this small application. I am looking for ways to improve my code, as well as ways to increase its efficiency.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Manchester.h"

int main()
{
    int data[] = { 1, 1, 0, 0 }; // Some unencoded data
    int* encoded = Manchester::encode(data, 4);
    int* decoded = Manchester::decode(encoded, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

**Manchester.cpp**

```
#include "Manchester.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>


#ifdef DEBUG
    #include <iostream>
#endif

int *Manchester::encode(int *data, int length)
{
    int *output = new int[length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        // Work out the array indexes to use
        int bid = i * 2;
        int nbid = bid + 1;

        // Get the data
        int real = data[i];

        int bit = 0;
        int nbit = 0;

        // Work out what it is
        switch (real)
        {
        case 0:
            bit = MANCHESTER_ZERO[0] - '0'; // Subtract 48 to work out the real value
            nbit = MANCHESTER_ZERO[1] - '0';
            break;
        case 1:
            bit = MANCHESTER_ONE[0] - '0'; // Subtract 48 to work out the real value
            nbit = MANCHESTER_ONE[1] - '0';
            break;
        }

        #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "[encode] " << real << " [" << bit << nbit << "]" << std::endl;
        #endif

        output[bid] = bit;
        output[nbid] = nbit;
    }

    return output;
}

int *Manchester::decode(int *data, int length)
{
    if ((length % 2) != 0)
    {
        throw std::range_error("length is not a multiple of 2");
    }

    int *output = new int[length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++)
    {
        // Work out the array indexes to use
        int bid = i * 2;
        int nbid = bid + 1;

        // Get the data
        int bit = data[bid];
        int nbit = data[nbid];

        // Put the data into a stringstream for comparison
        std::stringstream con;
        con << bit << nbit;
        const char* sbit = con.str().c_str();

        int real = 0;

        // Compare the data and work out the value
        if (strcmp(sbit, MANCHESTER_ONE) == 0)
        {
            real = 1;
        } else if (strcmp(sbit, MANCHESTER_ZERO) == 0) {
            real = 0;
        }

        #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "[decode] bit: " << bit << nbit << " [" << real << "]" << std::endl;
        #endif

        output[i] = real;
    }

    return output;
}
```

**Manchester.h**

```
#ifndef MANCHESTER_H
#define MANCHESTER_H

#define DEBUG

#define MANCHESTER_ONE "01"
#define MANCHESTER_ZERO "10"

class Manchester
{
public:
    static int *encode(int *data, int length);
    static int *decode(int *data, int length);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't return and use a local dynamic variable. You must free it up before going out of scope, see this post about [memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-c-code-project). Also, I don't see the logic by making the length of `decode` twice in `encode` since you will divide it to half w/c is equal to length of array.

Comment: Ah yes, I just spotted the useless dividing and multiplying inside encode, thanks ^_^ I'll take a look at the memory leak post too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Manipulating bits

One of the areas where your code may be improved is the way it handles and compares bits. You are using `char*` strings to represent bits while you could have used `unsigned` values and bitwise operations to speed up most of your operations. Actually, you should even replace every `int` representing bits by `unsigned` since the representation of `unsigned` values is known and they are the tool to use when representing bits.

- You can replace the `MANCHESTER_ONE` and `MANCHESTER_ZERO` definitions by:

  ```
  #define MANCHESTER_ONE 1u
  #define MANCHESTER_ZERO 2u
  ```

  `1u` is `0b01` in binary and `2u` is `0b10`.
- Then you can change the following bit of code in `encode`:

  ```
  switch (real)
  {
  case 0:
      bit = MANCHESTER_ZERO[0] - '0'; // Subtract 48 to work out the real value
      nbit = MANCHESTER_ZERO[1] - '0';
      break;
  case 1:
      bit = MANCHESTER_ONE[0] - '0'; // Subtract 48 to work out the real value
      nbit = MANCHESTER_ONE[1] - '0';
      break;
  }
  ```

  By the way, the `switch` is useless since your are only checking for two values. You can replace it by a regular `if`:

  ```
  if (real == 0)
  {
      bit = (MANCHESTER_ZERO >> 1) & 1;
      nbit = MANCHESTER_ZERO & 1;
  }
  else // real == 1
  {
      bit = (MANCHESTER_ONE >> 1) & 1;
      nbit = MANCHESTER_ONE & 1;
  }
  ```

  Since we replaced the strings `MANCHESTER_*` by `unsigned` values, we use bitwise `AND`s instead of array subtracts.
- A gain in efficiency may be obtained by refactoring this piece of code:

  ```
  // Put the data into a stringstream for comparison
  std::stringstream con;
  con << bit << nbit;
  const char* sbit = con.str().c_str();

  int real = 0;

  // Compare the data and work out the value
  if (strcmp(sbit, MANCHESTER_ONE) == 0)
  {
      real = 1;
  } else if (strcmp(sbit, MANCHESTER_ZERO) == 0) {
      real = 0;
  }
  ```

  `std::stringstream` is known to be slow since you have to convert your integer values into strings first before performing operations on them. In a `for` loop, it may be a big performance loss. Here is how you can refactor this bit of code:

  ```
  // Put the bits in an unsigned
  unsigned sbit = (bit << 1) | nbit;

  // Check only for MANCHESTER_ONE,
  // assuming that it will be equal
  // to MANCHESTER_ZERO if not
  int real = int(sbit == MANCHESTER_ONE);
  ```

  As said in the comments, I make the assumption that once computed, `sbit` can only be equal to `MANCHESTER_ONE` or `MANCHESTER_ZERO` and nothing else.

## General advice about C++

I cannot see any hint that you are using C++11, therefore I will review your code as C++03 code:

- As said in the comments, allocating memory in a function and not deallocating it is not a good idea. You should simply use a `std::vector` to represent your arrays of numbers.
- `#define` is to be avoided whenever possible in C++. Consider using `const` variables instead.
- The standard way to check whether you are debugging is `#ifndef NDEBUG` (the double negative is kind of ugly, but it's the standard way).
- In C++, it is useless to write `return 0;` at the end of `main`. If no `return` statement is given, the compiler will add an implicit `return 0;`.
- If the `MANCHESTER_*` constants are not used anywhere else, you can define them as `private` `static const` variables of the class `Machester`.

---

Here is your code once refactored:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

class Manchester
{
public:

    static std::vector<unsigned> encode(const std::vector<unsigned>& data, unsigned length)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned> output(length * 2);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

            // Work out the array indexes to use
            unsigned bid = i * 2;
            unsigned nbid = bid + 1;

            // Get the data
            unsigned real = data[i];

            unsigned bit = 0;
            unsigned nbit = 0;

            // Work out what it is
            if (real == 0)
            {
                bit = (ZERO >> 1) & 1;
                nbit = ZERO & 1;
            }
            else // real == 1
            {
                bit = (ONE >> 1) & 1;
                nbit = ONE & 1;
            }

            #ifndef NDEBUG
                std::cout << "[encode] " << real << " [" << bit << nbit << "]" << std::endl;
            #endif

            output[bid] = bit;
            output[nbid] = nbit;
        }

        return output;
    }

    static std::vector<unsigned> decode(const std::vector<unsigned>& data, unsigned length)
    {
        if ((length % 2) != 0)
        {
            throw std::range_error("length is not a multiple of 2");
        }

        std::vector<unsigned> output(length / 2);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++)
        {
            // Work out the array indexes to use
            unsigned bid = i * 2;
            unsigned nbid = bid + 1;

            // Get the data
            unsigned bit = data[bid];
            unsigned nbit = data[nbid];

            // Put the data into an unsigned int
            unsigned sbit = (bit << 1) | nbit;

            // Check only for MANCHESTER_ONE,
            // assuming that it will be equal
            // to MANCHESTER_ZERO if not
            unsigned real = unsigned(sbit == ONE);

            #ifndef NDEBUG
                std::cout << "[decode] bit: " << bit << nbit << " [" << real << "]" << std::endl;
            #endif

            output[i] = real;   
        }
        return output;
    }

private:

    static const unsigned ONE;
    static const unsigned ZERO;
};

const unsigned Manchester::ONE = 1u;
const unsigned Manchester::ZERO = 2u;


int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<unsigned> vec_t;

     // Some unencoded data
    unsigned data[] = { 1u, 1u, 0u, 0u };
    // Initialize vector with array
    vec_t vec(data, data+sizeof(data) / sizeof(unsigned));

    vec_t encoded = Manchester::encode(vec, 4);
    vec_t decoded = Manchester::decode(encoded, 8);
}
```

You can find a live working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8380911333b19863) at Coliru.